# Problems with 100% viewport width in mobile?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

2 of my pages in mobile aren't going full 100% width, you can see it [here](http://melmencarelli.com/about/).

I've got `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` in my code, and I've tried various variations of it. The problem could be in my `pages.php`file, since the rest of the pages are custom templates?

Here's my code for page.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 51em;
  background: none;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#primary {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I don't know if I'm missing something that's wordpress related, or messed up my code (I'm a beginner at coding), or what. Confused because my other pages are working alright and I can't see anything in the code that's causing it to be that thin width.

*btw - haven't figured out the nav in mobile yet, but you can see that it works in the other pages by checking out the link:
[Home](http://melmencarelli.com/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Everything is correct but I see `scroll` because your `footer` got some `non-responsive` codes.*

**in this page:**

> http://melmencarelli.com/about/

first, add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `#footer-container` and set `width: 100%` like this:

```
#footer-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

then, set `width: 100%` for `.footer-info`, like this:

```
.footer-info {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

---

**in this page:**

> http://melmencarelli.com/

Do above instruction then set `width: 100%` for:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 0px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 0px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 0px)
html input[type="button"] {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

also I see this:

```
<div class="home-button">
<a href="http://melmencarelli.com/mentoring/">
<input type="button" value="HOW WE WORK TOGETHER">
</a>
</div>
```

I recommend you to use this:

```
<div class="home-button">
<a href="http://melmencarelli.com/mentoring/">
<button>HOW WE WORK TOGETHER</button>
</a>
</div>
```

*well, all looks good!*

Comment: Awesome, thanks man. So I made the changes, but I'm getting crazy action in that about page still. I can't seem to link a screenshot here but in chrome's inspector under Iphone 5 it'll show it. 

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your welcome. Add your screenshot to first Post (Question) then let me know. @MelanieMencarelli

Comment: Looks like it's a `chrome` issue .. No idea but still trying to find out. but I checked your website on my `iphone 6` and looks good, [See](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sJykD.png) @MelanieMencarelli | Let you know if I found that `chrome` issue.

Comment: But I see your nav.. I guess there is a `viewport` issue also. and you can check your website in [Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/)

Comment: Aw yeah, you're right! Weird, something must have fixed it because in my iphone it was looking the same as it was in chrome. 

One final question: To make that about page mobile friendly (aka, not displaying as if it was being viewed on a desktop), are those just media-query changes or does that have to do with the viewport width code (don't know the proper term here)?

edit: aha, yeah you answered before I hit send. I'll check it out.

Comment: @MelanieMencarelli you got 3 `viewport` in your page, remove all `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` then put one in `header` this > `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
` then let me know.